# Facebook and their method for collecting data - reverse engineering the methods?

Tags: javascript, facebook, reverse-engineering

So apparently, Facebook collects huge amount of data from user, and not just from hitting the Like button, but also the amount of time that user has spent looking at some post by someone ( reading friends status update ). Is there a method to see what am I actually sending to Facebook and when (time is relevant). Can I view those requests in Windows 7?

Is it possible to do reverse engineering on this particular topic?

Answer (score 1):

This will be available in all browsers but if you have access to Chrome then go to "View" and then "Developer" and then "Developer Tools".

From here select the "Network" tab.

You can then see all traffic travelling between your browser and the internet. You can filter this list down based on the Domain Name, e.g. facebook or any other aliases they use.

Click on any item in the list and then you can see the request and response.

This should help you to get started.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that simple..

Facebook will use their own format, not like the most simple aka REST / JSON applications.

Facebook is making it very very hard to read/understand their APIs, obviously...

They will use some kind of their own binary data implementation, so really if you look at the post data, its just number, some (maybe) encrypted token like data, stored in a base64 format.. what ever..

Additionally, FB is using a lot of AI processing, this is no rocket-science anymore.. The internal APIs could also work based on that. So reverse-engineering FB makes no sense. Just write you own.

I also think, that many very good IT specialists are already trying it. Companies like FB will also make internal contests on this topic, to make their APIs even more secure. Actually, if you do some Online Banking, you will find more useful information on what data was send, then on FB.